# Cant dynamically update text in svg using SVGWEB, Embedded SVG Fonts, and Flash Renderer

Tags: svg

I am having a problem with the flash viewer and embedded SVG fonts.
I am dynamically changing the content of a  element using
javascript. When I do this with the default system font, the text
updates beautifully, however when I use an embedded SVG font and the
flash viewer, changing the context of the  element does not
delete the previous contents, it just prints the new contents over the
old.

This only happens with the flash renderer. If I use the native viewers
on firefox or safari, the embedded fonts work perfectly.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a better way to dynamically
change the value of a text element besides doing this:

svgDoc.getElementById('text1').childNodes[0].nodeValue = customText

Answer (score 3):

There are some other ways to set text content sure. If you are ok with the children of that node being overwritten, then textContent is quite handy for example:

`svgDoc.getElementById('text1').textContent = customText` ([spec link](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent))

If you need very fine-grained control you can look up the [Text node properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772).

I guess you can always try removing the child elements of your text element if that's what causes repainting issues in SVGWeb. Also you should [create an SVGWeb issue](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/issues/list) so that the bug can get fixed in a future release.